# Robot rotates angularly in rviz when linealy accelerated using teleop

Tags: navigation, odometry, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am new to ros. I'm trying to implement `gmapping` on  my custom robot. I am in the initial stage and using `ros_arduino_bridge` to publish the odometry and control the motors. I have used `teleop_twist_keyboard` to manually navigate the real robot. While doing so, if I linearly move the robot, the robot rotates angularly in rviz,i.e when real robot moves forward, robot model in rviz rotates left.  Similarly, when real robot moves in reverse, robot model in rviz rotates right.So I assume that the linear and angular motion are inverted in rviz and real motion. Where would be the probable mistake? How to rectify it?

Here is the odom data published:

```
header: 
  seq: 1110
  stamp: 
    secs: 1521979250
    nsecs: 547859907
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -0.0323011953631
      y: 0.131932086548
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.668663666459
      w: -0.743564994575
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
header: 
  seq: 1111
  stamp: 
    secs: 1521979250
    nsecs: 663502931
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -0.0323011953631
      y: 0.131932086548
```

If any other data is needed, please let me know. Thanks in advance.
z: 0.0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286475/robot-rotates-angularly-in-rviz-when-linealy-accelerated-using-teleop/) by [kilovolt](https://answers.ros.org/users/34302/kilovolt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-03-26**:
The tf from odom to base_link is used by rviz, not the odom topic. More information is needed, e.g. where the tf is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I faced the same problem earlier and I could solve the same by manipulating the signs of the encoder and thus getting proper direction reflected. That is for the robot moving forward, both the encoders must have the same positive sign and increment. Similarly for rotation the clockwise rotation will have left encoder positive and right encoder negative and vice versa.
If your are using `ros_arduino_bridge` try changing the signs of the encoder data in the `encoder_driver` file. It looks something like this

```
long readEncoder(int i) {
    if (i == LEFT) 0-return left_enc_pos;
    else return right_enc_pos;
  }
```

For example change the `0-return left_enc_pos` to  `return left_enc_pos` and try to match the convention for encoder as stated above.

---

Originally posted by [ashikmh14](https://answers.ros.org/users/33962/ashikmh14/) with karma: 41 on 2018-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1